# the usage of gscatter3

Tags: matlab, plot

I try to use gscatter3 to draw the pca plot, but it always comes out this error.

The link to [gscatter3](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/37970-gscatter3)

Thanks in advance for any help!

```
>> stage265_tran=stage265';
>> [~, scores,pcvars]=pca(stage265_tran);
>> x265=zscore(scores(:,1));
>> y265=zscore(scores(:,2));
>> z265=zscore(scores(:,3));
>> gscatter3(x265,y265,z265,cellstr(tmp265),{'b','g','m'},{'.','.','.'},15)
```

Comment: Why do you put variables between double quotes in the cell array `tmp1`? IMO you should try without.

Comment: Thank you for your help!